# Having some trouble with a assignment in c++

Tags: c++

I have a assignment I've been working on and my code is working but the results are off by a hair.  I know the issue has to do with rounding but I just can't seem to figure out where the issue lies. I've included the assignment details as well as the results i'm getting versus the expected result.  Any help is appreciated.

Link for images https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8tk8.jpg

'''

```
// This program will display the size of a population for given number of years
// taking into account annual birth and death rates as well as the number of 
// people who move away and move into the area.

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Function prototype 
double calculatePop (double, double, double, int, int);



int main ()
{
    double P;           // Starting population
    double  B;      // Annual birth rate 
    double  D;      // Annual death rate 
    int A;          // Average number of people who arrive
    int M;          // Average number of people who move away
    int nYears;     // The number of years to display

    cout << "This program calculates population change." << endl;

    // Set numeric formatting 
    cout << setprecision(0) << fixed;

    // Get starting population size
    cout << "Enter the starting population size: ";
    cin >> P;
    while (P<2){
        cout << "Starting population must be 2 or more.";
        cout << "Please re-enter:";
        cin >> P;}

    // Get the annual birth rate
    cout << "Enter the annual birth rate (as % of current population): ";
    cin >> B;
    while (B<0){
        cout << "Birth rate percent cannot be negative.";
        cout << "Please re-enter:";
        cin >> B;}

    B/=100;

    // Get annual death rate
    cout << "Enter the annual death rate (as % of current population): ";
    cin >> D;
    while (D<0){
        cout << "Death rate percent cannot be negative.";
        cout << "Please re-enter:";
        cin >> D;}

    D/=100;

    // Get number of people who arrive

    cout << "How many individuals move into the area each year? ";
    cin >> A;
    while (A<0){
        cout << "Arrivals cannot be negative.";
        cout << "Please re-enter:";
        cin >> A;}

    // Get number of people who move away
    cout << "How many individuals leave the area each year? ";
    cin >> M;
    while (M<0){
        cout << "Departures cannot be negative.";
        cout << "Please re-enter:";
        cin >> M;}

    // Get number of years to see data for
    cout << "For how many years do you wish to view population changes? " << endl << endl;
    cin >> nYears;
    while (nYears<1){
        cout << "Years must be one or more.";
        cout << "Please re-enter:";
        cin >> nYears;}

    cout << "Starting population: " << P << endl << endl;

    //Display the population to user
    for (int y=1; y<=nYears; y++)
    {
        P = calculatePop(P, B, D, A, M);
        cout << "Population at the end of year " << y << " is " << P << ".\n";  
    }
}

double calculatePop (double P, double B, double D, int A, int M)
{
    double N;       //New Population Size 
    N = P + (B*P) - (D*P) + A - M;
    return N;
}
```

'''

Comment: What inputs are you using, what outputs do you expect, and what outputs do you get?  [Edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: I realized i didn't include the link to images. I have added the link to my question.

Comment: Include those details as _text_, not images.

Comment: Given that your results are too high by 1 about 50% of the time, it seems likely that the "correct" solution rounds down while yours rounds to the nearest integer.

Comment: That is what I figure is happening. I'm just not having any luck pinpointing why thats happeneing

Comment: @Amin *but I just can't seem to figure out where the issue lies.* -- Use the debugger that comes with your compiler toolset.  Second, you could have also printed out some intermediate values to see what they are.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The information in those pictures is a lot of text to write out. I don't see the issue with providing a link to the actual results versus typing out entire walls of text.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm using myprogramminlglab and there is no debugger :(

Comment: @Amin All modern-day compilers come with debuggers.  I do not know what "myprogramminglab" is supposed to mean, but some way you compiled your code using an IDE of some sort or a command-line, thus a debugger should be available.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Amin Try outputing the result using `int(P)` in the last `cout`. Setting `setprecision(0)` will round the number to the nearest integer while `int(P)` will remove the decimals, which seems to be what happens in the expected result.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé This worked as far as getting the correct values. Thanks.
The website in which I have to submit this is doesn't have a debugger. It just highlights and yells about where your mistakes are without giving you any advice. Now that my calculations are providing the correct answers it's yelling about my formatting. When I fix the issues it points out, it then complains about a different area. I fix that and it goes back to complaining about the first area. This is not the first time it's done this.  I have emailed my professor to file a complaint.

Comment: @Amin -- You could find out the compiler that is used at the website, and in all probablility, it is free of charge (g++, clang, Visual Studio Community Ed., etc.).  Then install whatever the compiler is on your computer and use it to debug the problems.  Once you have the program working locally, then submit it to the website.

Comment: "I don't see the issue with providing a link to the actual results versus typing out " - the picture is unreadable, no matter how much I zoom.

Answer (score 1):

The value is correctly calculated but not outputted the same way as in the assignment. Setting `setprecision(0)` along with `fixed` will round the number to the nearest integer while the result shown in the assignment is the truncated number. To truncate the result, use

```
cout << "Population at the end of year " << y << " is " << int(P) << ".\n";
```

Comment: That worked to help me get the correct values. Thank you.

Comment: @eerorika When used with `fixed`, `setprecision` specifies the number of decimals, regardless of the integer part.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé oh sorry, I did not notice `fixed`. The answer is correct..